# Is there a way to power down an AirPort Time Capsule gracefully?

Tags: time-capsule

There is no obvious way to power down an AirPort Time Capsule in a graceful way. Naturally, you typically won't be powering the thing on and off on a regular basis, but I'm surprised there doesn't seem to be a way to do it given that the device has a storage component that might be damaged by a sudden shutdown.

Is there a way to power down an AirPort Time capsule gracefully?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Apple (from the [Time Capsule manual](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1645/en_US/airport_time_capsule_80211ac_setup.pdf))

**Using Your AirPort Time Capsule Safely**

- The only way to shut off power completely to your AirPort Time
  Capsule is to disconnect it from the power source.

If you want to go above and beyond, you can be sure that all users all logged off, and not performing a backup through the Airport Utility, but this is not necessary...

Comment: If the device appears mounted, then good idea to confirm that a Time Machine backup is not in progress, followed by "ejecting" the device.

Answer (score 3):

For my AirPort Extreme, I use Airport Utility to restart the Airport, watch for the lights on the front, at the lights off phase I pull the plug, just slightly more graceful.

Comment: How do you know is more graceful? Actually you are risking to kill the power right during some critical boot process part ...